# Set Founder Adminstrator Permissions phpbb

Tags: admin, phpbb, user-permissions, phpbb3

I would like to install a new style in my forum.
As an administrator I go to the control panel and missing the `Styles` tab.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're not listed as a 'Founder' then you probably don't have the permission to see it. Only a founder can assign founder permissions to other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the styles tab by going to the list of users and then navigate to the adminstrator profile. From there on the way to the admin control panel is quite easy.

As @Eeji mentioned, a user cannot set permission to himself. Even not asministrator.

Comment: can you tell what are the actual  steps you did to get the style tab ?

Comment: @prime, Don't you have the styles tab on the administrator control panel? Or you didn;t manage the administartor control panel at all?

Comment: No. I have the costomise tab instead. I'm using the latest version of it. Then I switch back to the older version where there is a style tab. don't know why but the latest version seems not working properly for me.

Comment: I change the role in every thing to full access level in the latest one. but no difference.